# Trigger on manage currency if conversion rate changed

Tags: apex, trigger, multi-currency

is it possible to create a trigger if the conversion rate of any currency changed for active currency?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to an org that has multiple currencies enabled. The object that holds that information is CurrencyType and the field is ConversionRate. It only exist in orgs that have the multicurrency feature enabled. The [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf) doesn't show it as being triggerable. I don't have a multicurrency org available to double check for you. You can use Workbench to check the object's info.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can see what objects you can write triggers on is by going to Developer Console and trying to write a trigger for that object - if not listed, no go.

For example, in my multi-currency advanced currency management org, `DatedConversionRate` is not available for triggers.

A plausible solution if this is vital for you would be to write a daily scheduled job that queried `DatedConversionRate` for the current date and compare it against the value you captured on the previous run.